# can not link to FFTW library for Android NDK

Tags: android, android-studio, linker, fftw

I want to use FFTW3 for my Android NDK project. Therefore I build the library on MacOs for Android as follows:

```
./configure --host=aarch64-none-linux-android33 --enable-threads --enable-float
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

Then I linked it in `build.gradle`:

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
           cppFlags "-L/path/to/fftwf/.libs/ -lfftw3f_threads -lfftw3f -lm",
                    "-L/path/to/fftwf/threads/.libs/ ",
                    "-O3 -g --std=c++17 -fopenmp"
        }
}
```

Then I included FFTW into the CMake process of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library( demo SHARED native-lib.cpp )
# ....
add_subdirectory(fftwf)
include_directories(fftwf/api)

target_include_directories( fbi PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fftwf/api )
target_include_directories( fbi PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fftwf/threads/.libs )
target_link_libraries( demo fftw3 )
```

After including FFTW with `#include "fftwf/api/fftw3.h"` I get the following linking error:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: fftwf_threads_set_callback
>>> referenced by fftw-bench.c:101   (/path/to/fftwf_3.3.10/tests/fftw-bench.c:101)
>>>               fftwf_3.3.10/CMakeFiles/bench.dir/tests/fftw-bench.c.o:(useropt)
```

I could not find anything in the FFTW3.3.10 docs that specify how to correctly link the library when using threads. Since `fftwf_threads_set_callback` is the first occurrence of a call to the FFTW thread library, I assume that something went wrong in the build process, but I could not find any flaws when comparing to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by building FFTW with CMake:

```
add_subdirectory(fftw)

add_library( demo SHARED native-lib.cpp )

target_include_directories( demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fftwf/api )
target_include_directories( demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fftwf/threads )

target_link_libraries( demo fftw3f fftw3f_threads )
```

Somehow the fftw/CMakeLists.txt did not enable single precision and threads, like I specified in the `./configure` flags, so I manually enabled it:

```
option (ENABLE_THREADS "Use pthread for multithreading" ON)
option (ENABLE_FLOAT "single-precision" ON)
```

I initially also used the `--enable-neon` flag, but that also yield a ld error and I could not find a way to manually adjust the CMakeLists, so I had to set `#define HAVE_NEON 0`.